# Delete duplicate prefix in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to delete a prefix like this one in a database r8oi9_ which was made by mistake. (not keeping the original prefix while restoring the website)

I want to completely wipe anything with this prefix and not touch other prefixes in the same database. I followed the answer posted in that question:
[SQL: deleting tables with prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589278/sql-deleting-tables-with-prefix)
but there was a warning saying:

> /!\ This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox,
>   Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

This is the code I used into SQL:

```
> SELECT CONCAT(  'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT( table_name ) ,  ';' )
AS statement FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name LIKE'r8oi9_%';
```

maybe there is something I am missing, as inserting the name of the database someplace? executing the generated script? Where do I see this script to execute it?

ps.I am an ignorant as it comes to MSQL. Apologies if questions are silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple, in front of my eyes. However, I did it by hand and not with script which would be better and faster..
So, I clicked the corresponding database's name and then the a screen view like this appeared to me (with "Structure" tab selected)
[image]

so I checked all boxes corresponding to r8oi9_ prefix carefully not to check the prefixes I wanted to keep (i.e. the prefix mdl_ as the picture above shows).
Then I chose the "DROP" choice from dropdown menu saying "With Selected:".
Then confirming the drop, I wiped all tables I didn't need.
A script instead of this would be much more useful for really large databases.