# How do I drop all wordpress tables in my database?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a WordPress site that I no longer want. But my databse is now full of hundreds of tables created by WordPress. I can't seem to find a way to drop tables with prefix, so What is the easiest way to get rid of all of these tables?

Comment: Here is a way [SQL: deleting tables with prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589278/sql-deleting-tables-with-prefix), on a first google search :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: deleting tables with prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589278/sql-deleting-tables-with-prefix)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your hosting cpanel account. Select "phpMyadmin". Once you will go to phpMyadmin you will see list of database. Select the right database and then select all the tables and select drop. Please see image below.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much :D